# Int to Float conversion: no instance for Num [Int]

Tags: haskell, floating-point, int

I need to use the `map` function to get for example pence to pounds conversion.
Sorry for the stupid question.. but I am a beginner.

```
del :: Int -> Float
del x =  ( fromIntegral x ) / 100

pounds :: [Int] -> [Float]
pounds = map del
```

and I get this error..

```
*Main> pounds 45
<interactive>:90:8:
    No instance for (Num [Int])
      arising from the literal `45'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Int])
    In the first argument of `pounds', namely `45'
    In the expression: pounds 45
    In an equation for it': it = pounds 45
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you typed

```
ghci> pounds 45
```

at the prompt. But `pounds` expects a list (of `Int`) as its argument. You should either use

```
ghci> del 45
```

there, or

```
ghci> pounds [45]
```

Since integer literals have an implicit `fromInteger`, GHC tries to find the conversion `fromInteger :: Integer -> [Int]`, which would require an `instance Num [Int]`, but it can't find one, that's the error it reports.

Answer (score 4):

`pounds` only works on lists, but you used it on a number.

```
pounds [45]
```

would work fine.

Usually when the compiler says its missing an instance, it usually means your argument is the wrong type or missing.

Answer (score 2):

The argument for `pounds` needs to be a *list* of `Int`, not an isolated `Int`.

Try doing `pounds [45]` instead.