# Why can an invalid list expression such as 2:1 be assigned to a variable, but not printed?

Tags: haskell

In the ghci terminal, the following variable assignment is allowed:

```
a = [2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]
```

However, when `a` is printed, the following error occurs:

```
- No instance for (Num [Integer]) arising from a use of 'it'
- In the first argument of 'print', namely 'it'
- In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Why is this?

Comment: `x` is assigned every element of `[1, 1, 1]` one after the other, but you can't use `1` as a list, however the second argument of `(:)` is supposed to be one.

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you.  Any idea why the assignment itself does not produce the same error?

Comment: @another_rando Exactly which bit is "the assignment itself"?

Comment: Here's a short answer. The type of `a` is important here: `a :: (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]`. So, you need a type `a` to instantiate it at, such that both `a` and `[a]` is an instance of `Num`. That's why it's accepted. Since ghci defaults to `Integer`, and `[Integer]` isn't an instance of `Num`, you get a type-error. You can concoct a type of your own and define `instance Num [MyType]` for it, so this goes through. Whether that's advisable is another question; but it's perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @another_rando See https://pastebin.com/3QCcenja for an example of how to make sense of a type like this. Again, probably not the best practice; but it explains why the definition of `a` is accepted in the first place.

Comment: @alias when you replace `pounds` with `(2:)` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964026/442760) you get an accurate description of what the problem is.

Comment: This would treat x as a scalar element, and so would work fine: `xs = [ [2,x] | x <- [1, 1, 1]]`

Comment: If you have a base Num-enabled type, say `bnt`, you can choose to regard lists of type [bnt] as formal MacLaurin series (that is, unlimited polynomials) in variable X with coefficients of type bnt. If you enable the `FlexibleInstances` Haskell extension, this can probably lead you to a proper Num instance for [bnt]. So you could match the type constraint `(Num bnt, Num [bnt])` as mentioned by alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you were able to define it like this in GHCi is that you didn't specify what type this is supposed to be. Good practice is to always add type signatures to top-level definitions – though to be fair, it's very common not to do it in GHCi.

See, some expressions you can write out have bogus types, though they do typecheck. Your code is one example, its type is

```
ghci> :t [2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]
(Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]
```

What does that mean? Well, before I explain it let me explain the type of some simpler expression, which actually do make sense:

```
ghci> :t 'x'
Char
```

This one should be self-explanatory.

```
ghci> :t 37
Num a => a
```

This one perhaps isn't self-explanatory. Shouldn't it be something simple like `Int` instead?

Well, the trick is, Haskell's number literals are more flexible. They don't have necessarily any particular type at all, but take on whatever type is required by the context. The reason is that it allows you to write things like `sqrt 2` and have the result be of type `Double`. In this case the literal `2` also has type `Double`. (Other languages achieve this by doing automatic conversion from `Int` to `Double`, which has however a bunch of downsides which I won't get into here.)

The only condition the compiler imposes is that the type required by the context must have an instance of the `Num` class. In case of `Double`, that instance looks like this (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Float.html#line-545), with a bunch of scary low-level details you don't need to worry about:

```
instance  Num Double  where
    (+)         x y     =  plusDouble x y
    (-)         x y     =  minusDouble x y
    negate      x       =  negateDouble x
    (*)         x y     =  timesDouble x y
    abs         x       =  fabsDouble x
    signum x | x > 0     = 1
             | x < 0     = negateDouble 1
             | otherwise = x -- handles 0.0, (-0.0), and NaN

    {-# INLINE fromInteger #-}
    fromInteger i = D# (integerToDouble# i)
```

Normally, the compiler will give you an error whenever you attempt to use a number literal in a type-context that does not have a `Num` instance. In your example, the context requires a list. A simpler example with the same problem is

```
reverse 5 :: [Integer]
```

Well, common sense tells us lists aren't numbers and thus incompatible with `Num`. The compiler doesn't know that though, and indeed theoretically you *could* define such an instance! (**Don't** do it, I'm just playing devil's advocate here)

```
instance Num [Integer] where
  fromInteger i = [523,i,916]
```

and then your code will suddenly work... I mean, not *work* in the sense of doing anything right, but evaluate without an error message:

```
ghci> reverse 5 :: [Integer]
[916,5,523]
```

Because there isn't in actual reality an `instance Num [Integer]`, you'd think that writing this would normally give an error. However, a quirk of Haskell's typeclass mechanism is that you can never be sure that an instance does not exist until you have narrowed it down to a specific type. But when you define simply

```
a = reverse 5
```

then the compiler will initially attempt to give it the most general type possible on to it, and attach any requirements (nonsensical or not) on to it as constraints.

```
ghci> :t a
a :: Num [a] => [a]
```

The actual solution is of course to *not use numbers as lists*. Perhaps what you actually meant to do was using the numbers as list *elementa*, which you can for example in this way:

```
ghci> [[2,x] | x <- [1, 1, 1]]
[[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have hit, perhaps by accident, some interesting properties of the Haskell type system.

In order to complement [the excellent answer by leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77822967/11282404),
this answer will get you to a point where expression `[2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]` is actually printable.
This will justify why this expression is not immediately flagged as an error by *ghci*.

Let's start a *ghci* session:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> a = [2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]

 <interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        a :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XFlexibleContexts
 λ> 
 λ> a = [2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]
 λ> :type a
 a :: (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]
 λ> 
 λ> :type 2:1
 2:1 :: (Num a, Num [a]) => [a]
 λ> 
 λ> a

 <interactive>:7:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Integer]) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
 λ>
```

For expression `2:1` to make sense, *ghci* must be able to interpret the literal `1` as a list, because it is the right operand of operator `:`.

If lists of numbers get equipped with an instance of class `Num`, as class `Num` provides a `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` function, in an appropriate context expression `fromInteger 1` will be interpreted as `((fromInteger (1::Integer)) :: *SomeListType*)`.

Providing such a `Num` instance to plain lists of numbers means that expressions such as `[1,2,3] * [6,7]` will become legal. This is unusual and frowned upon, so we will operate in two steps:

1. provide a `Num` instance for a polynomial type: `newtype Poly nt = Poly [nt]`
2. tell ghci to *derive* a `Num` instance for plain lists from the `Poly` `Num` instance

Polynomial arithmetics is well defined, with suitable properties of [associativity and distributivity](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/GHC-Num.html). The polynomial code is not central to our argument. Sample code for type `Poly`, to be hosted in file Poly.hs, is included at the end of this answer.

Checking:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :load Poly.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Poly             ( Poly.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> Poly [1,2] + Poly [2,1,7]
 Poly [3,3,7]
 λ> 
 λ> Poly [1,1] * Poly [1,1]
 Poly [1,2,1]
 λ>
```

the last line above just meaning that (1+x)²  == 1 + 2*x + x²

Now let's *derive* our `Num` instance for plain lists, thus bestowing polynomial arithmetics onto them. Using the [DerivingVia language extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html) as our key tool here.

```
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XStandaloneDeriving
 λ> :set -XDerivingVia
 λ> deriving via (Poly a)  instance Num a => Num [a]
 λ>
```

From that point onwards, numeric lists have their own instance of the `Num` class:

```
 λ>
 λ> ((fromInteger (42::Integer)) :: [Integer])
 [42]
 λ> 
 λ> 4:5:6
 [4,5,6]
 λ> 
 λ> [1,2] + [2,1,7]
 [3,3,7]
 λ> 
 λ> [1,1] * [1,1]
 [1,2,1]
 λ> 
 λ> a = [2:x | x <- [1, 1, 1]]
 λ> :type a
 a :: Num a => [[a]]
 λ>
```

And we note that the type of expression `a` is now simpler, as constraint `Num [a]` is automatically satisfied if you have `Num a`.

As expected, expression `a` is now printable:

```
 λ> 
 λ> a
 [[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]]
 λ>
```

Voilà !

**Note 1:** we are **not** claiming here that it is a sound Haskell programming idea to equip naked lists of numbers with a `Num` instance. In fact, it's probably not. The point is just that it is technically feasible.

**Note 2:** the `DerivingVia` extension is not central to the argument.
The `Num` instance for lists can be built manually from the polynomial code, something like this:

```haskell
instance Num a => Num [a]  where
    fromInteger n = [fromInteger n]
    xs * ys = getCoeffs ((Poly xs) * (Poly ys))
    ... etc ...
```

However, using the extension is shorter and less error prone.

---

### Sample code for a minimalistic polynomial module:

```haskell
-- Module for polynomials:

module Poly (Poly(), getCoeffs)  where

import Data.List(unfoldr)

newtype Poly nt = Poly [nt]  deriving  (Show)

getCoeffs :: Num nt => Poly nt -> [nt]
getCoeffs (Poly cs) = if (null cs)  then  [0]  else  cs

instance (Eq nt, Num nt)  =>  Eq (Poly nt)  where
    pa == pb  =  (getCoeffs pa) == (getCoeffs pb)

norm :: Num nt => Poly nt -> Poly nt
norm p = Poly (getCoeffs p)


instance Num nt  =>  Num (Poly nt)  where
    fromInteger n    = Poly [fromInteger n]
    pa + pb          = polyAdd pa pb
    pa * pb          = polyMul pa pb
    negate (Poly cs) = norm $ Poly $ map negate cs
    abs (Poly cs)    = norm $ Poly $ map abs cs
    signum (Poly cs) = if (null cs)  then  Poly [0]
                                     else  Poly [signum $ head cs]


{-
  Function paddedZip is used for polynomial addition, as expression
  paddedZip 0 0 [1,2] [2,3,9] evaluates to [(1,2),(2,3),(0,9)]
-}
paddedZip :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
paddedZip adv bdv = go   where
    go [] []          =  []
    go (x:xs) []      =  (x,bdv) : go xs []
    go [] (y:ys)      =  (adv,y) : go [] ys
    go (x:xs) (y:ys)  =  (x,y)   : go xs ys

polyAdd :: Num nt => Poly nt -> Poly nt -> Poly nt
polyAdd (Poly acs) (Poly bcs) = norm $ Poly $ map (\(x,y) -> x+y) pairs  where
    pairs = paddedZip 0 0 acs bcs

{-
  Function layeredPairLists is used for polynomial multiplication, as expression
  layeredPairLists [0,1,2] [0,1,2,3,4] evaluates to:
 [ [(0,0)],
   [(0,1),(1,0)]
   [(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)],
   [(0,3),(1,2),(2,1)],
   [(0,4),(1,3),(2,2)],
   [(1,4),(2,3)],
   [(2,4)] ]
-}
layeredPairLists :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
layeredPairLists as bs = unfoldr  stepFn  (clean [(as,bs)])  where
    clean = filter ( \(as,bs) -> (not (null as)  &&  not (null bs)) )
    stepFn pairs   =  let
                          res = map  (\(xs,ys) -> (head xs, head ys))  pairs
                          -- manage end of layer:
                          next [(as,bs)]  =  [(as,tail bs),(tail as,bs)]
                          next [] = []
                          -- common case:
                          next ((as,bs):ps) =  (as,tail bs) : (next ps)
                      in
                          if (null res) then  Nothing
                                        else  Just (res, clean $ next pairs)


polyMul :: Num nt => Poly nt -> Poly nt -> Poly nt
polyMul (Poly acs) (Poly bcs) = norm $ Poly pcs  where
    pcs = map  (sum . map (\(a,b) -> a*b))  (layeredPairLists acs bcs)
```

**Sanity check:**

As a basic sanity check for this module, we can define an expression for the Maclaurin serie (or infinite degree polynomial) associated
with function exp(k*x), and then check that all the coefficients of the serie for `exp(2*x) - exp(x)*exp(x))` are zero.

Using here rational numbers as defined in library module [Data.Ratio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) where fraction 3/7 is written as `3 % 7`.

```
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.Ratio
 λ> 
 λ> allFactorials = map snd (fp (0,1)) where fp (n,nf) = (n,nf) : fp (n+1, (nf*(n+1)))
 λ> take 8 allFactorials
 [1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040]
 λ> 
 λ> allPowers k   = pp (1::Integer)  where pp n = n : (pp (n*k))
 λ> take 8 $ allPowers 2
 [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]
 λ> 
 λ> mlExpK k = Poly $ map  (\(n,d) -> n % d)  $  zip (allPowers k) allFactorials
 λ>
 λ> :type mlExpK 2
 mlExpK 2 :: Poly (Ratio Integer)
 λ> 
 λ> diffExp = (mlExpK 2) - ((mlExpK 1) * (mlExpK 1))
 λ>
 λ> and $ take 100 $ map  (\c -> c==0)  (getCoeffs diffExp)
 True
 λ>
```